# AntiXSS 4.2.1 Instructions

Tags: .net, xss

So I spend almost 30 minutes looking for AntiXSS 4.2.1 instructions (Microsoft documentations are outdated) and couldnt find any..

I found that in old version, they use, but thats already deplecated.

```
AntiXss.HtmlEncode(string)
```

Can someone tell me how to make AntiXSS 4.2.1 work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found this, seems to be working

[Enhanced ASP.NET input sanitation with AntiXSS](http://gruntbuggly.blogspot.com/2011/01/enhanced-aspnet-input-sanitation-with.html)